# When Declaring a Function in C++, Does It Need to Have the Parameters That the Function Itself Has?

Tags: c++, function

(Please keep in mind I've only recently delved into C++ functions.)

Let's say that you want a function that will count from 1 to a specific number.

```
#include <iostream>
int countTo(int num);
int countTo(int num) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
  return num;
}
int main() {
  int num;
  std::cout << "Enter a number to which the program will count: ";
  std::cin >> num;
  countTo(num);
  return 0;
}
```

I've put the *same code* into the compiler, just without the parameters on the function declaration, like so:

```
int countTo();
int countTo(int num) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
  return num;
}
```

And it worked just as well. Do I need to include parameters when declaring `int countTo(int num)`? Or for any function?

`std::cout << "Thanks!!";`

Comment: It needs the parameter type, but not the parameter name. Your second piece of code is declaring two different functions.

Comment: If the definition of `int countTo(int num)` is seen before `main()` you don't need a forward declaration. Your `int countTo();` forward declaration is irrelevant, and never called anywhere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, I guess you're right! Before, when I tried doing functions, it didn't work and when I looked it up, it said to declare it like so. I probably just typed the function wrong. But I just tried it again without the `int countTo();` and it worked just fine. Interesting!

Comment: `int countTo();` and`int countTo(int num);` are not required at all. What was the purpose of having them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different things going on when you write this:

```
int countTo(int num) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
  }
  return num;
}
```

You are *declaring* a function called `countTo` that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, and you are also *defining* the function.

When you have the line above it saying

```
int countTo(int num);
```

you are declaring the same function, but not defining it.

When you changed that line to

```
int countTo();
```

you declared a different function (an *overload*) that takes no parameters. It doesn't matter that you didn't define that function, because no one ever tried to call it.